# ssh - close connection but keep executing remotely

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

let's say I have a `really-long-running.sh` ("really long" as in "hours").

I should like to have a remote machine execute it (and then shut down the local machine).

Unfortunately, I don't have much experience with ssh. Does this do what I want it to do or does it just mask the connection?

```
ssh user@host "bash -s " < really-long-running.sh &
```

**UPDATE**

It doesn't.

How then can I do this?

Comment: Some explanation: `ssh user@host "bash -s " < really-long-running.sh &` feeds `bash` running on the remote side with commands from local `.sh` file through `ssh` which runs locally in background. I think even if you make remote `bash` survive your disconnection, it will stop reading the script when `ssh` closes (when you shut down the local machine). Your script should be there on the remote side so the remote `bash` can read it when you disconnect. It's not enough to make `bash` survive your disconnection though – you still have to pick one of the solutions from the answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens to running processes when I lose a remote connection to a \*nix box?](http://superuser.com/questions/143925/what-happens-to-running-processes-when-i-lose-a-remote-connection-to-a-nix-box)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also `nohup` tool. From `man nohup`:

> nohup - run a command immune to hangups, with output to a non-tty

You can work step by step:

- `ssh` to the remote host
- `nohup /path/to/really-long-running.sh > /path/to/where-to-store-the-output &`
- may disconnect now;

or at once from your local machine:

```
ssh remote-host 'nohup /path/to/really-long-running.sh > /path/to/where-to-store-the-output &'
```

These examples require the script to be executable and reside on the remote host. In your code the script may not be executable and it is a local file.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use `screen` or `tmux` on the executing side - this allows you to disconnect and reconnect at will, giving you the option to read the output of your script at a later point in time.

Comment: ``screen`` doesn't work. as soon as I shut down the local machine, the session is terminated and the process consequently stopped. And judging by its description, it's the same with ``tmux``.

Comment: @User1291 How exactly do you use `screen` on the executing side so it is stopped as soon as you shut down the local machine?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski screen, then ssh into the remote, issue the command then ``Ctrl+A, D`` and shutdown.

Comment: @User1291 Use `screen` on the executing (remote) side.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I'm not really fond of the idea of having to install ``screen`` on all remotes I may want to access. I may not even be able to, in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

That 'may' do what you want (ssh in again afterwards and check with top?)

However, the ideal ways to do this are to start the command in a screen session (or tmux) which then allows you to disconnect from this running session, while still viewing what it's doing

Or you can ssh in, then 'disconnect' the process from the current terminal by backgrounding it and then disconnecting it using

```
ctrl + z
bg
disown
```

Or you can background the process from the command line via adding & to your command. You'll still need to disown it to stop it dying when you disconnect however.

Comment: I don't want to "background" the session, I want to actually end the session and be able to shut down the local machine.

Comment: The `disown` will prevent it from dying when you disconnect your ssh session.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `at` on the remote machine to schedule your job.

```
$ ssh remote-host
$ at now + 5 min
at> really-long-running.sh
at> <Ctrl-D>
job 1 at 2016-10-12 09:10
$ exit
```

You job will run per the schedule you define for the at job.  Check the manpage for [at](https://linux.die.net/man/1/at) for more details.  Default configuration allows any user to use at.